# How can I select every other line with multiple cursors in Sublime Text?

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

In Sublime Text 2, is it possible to instantly select every other (or odd/even) line and place multiple cursors on those lines?

Thanks.

Comment: Don't you want to accept an answer?

Answer (score 487):

1. Find: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
2. If regular expressions are not already enabled, enable them: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>
3. Type in the expression `.*\n.*\n`
4. Find all: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>
5. Press left arrow to get rid of the selections, leaving just the cursors: <kbd>←</kbd>
6. You now have a cursor at the start of every odd-numbered line. If you wanted even-numbered lines, press down: <kbd>↓</kbd>
7. Depending on the file, there might be one cursor missing right down the bottom of the file. Using the mouse (damn!) scroll to the bottom, hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, and click where the missing cursor should be to add it in.

Comment: You can also use `(.*\n){10}` for every 10 lines

Comment: [As a new improvement](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15598633/1238019) : `(.*(\n|$)){2}`

Comment: nice! @zessx's `(.*(\n|$)){2}` solution includes the last line

Comment: Just to note, in Sublime 2 running on OS X 10.11.5, the shortcut for RegEx search is Alt + Command + R. You can also enable RegEx search by pressing Command + F and then clicking the icon that looks like this: [ .* ]

Answer (score 108):

You can do it easily :

- Select all your lines, or the whole document <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>
- Add multiple selectors : <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> (and in Mac: Command + Shift + L)

EDIT :

- Or use [the great Joe Daley method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16273692/1238019) with `(.*(\n|$)){2}` expression

Comment: though not the right answer for this question, this is what i wanted. thanks for sharing

Comment: This solution is what I needed but not what the OP wants.

Answer (score 15):

I was searching for a way to select alternate lines in sublime.

Thanks to Joe Daley for a very good answer.
Though I realised that, if you use regex it would not select the last line in the file if there is no new-line at the end of the file.

I wanted to improve that answer but I don't seem to have enough reputation at the moment to comment on the answer above.

You can use the following search string with the regex turned on, and then press alt+enter. Followed by a left arrow. This would put a cursor each on alternate lines (same steps as explained by Joe Daley)

```
^.*\n.*$
```

Comment: This comment from 2014 just saved my morning. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

You can try with a plugin: `Tools/New Plugin...`

```py
import sublime_plugin


class ExpandSelectionToOtherLinesCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        self.view.window().run_command("expand_selection", {"to": "line"})
        start_region = self.view.sel()[0]
        self.view.window().run_command("select_all")
        self.view.sel().subtract(start_region)
```

Save this file in your `Packages/User`.

Then, add the key binding for that plugin:

```
{ "keys": ["super+alt+l"], "command": "expand_selection_to_other_lines" }
```

This command will select all other lines. When you have other lines selected, you can use `Split selection into lines` command (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>, <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> on Mac).

If you want to have everythnig in a single shortcut, you can modify the plugin like this:

```py
import sublime_plugin


class ExpandSelectionToOtherLinesCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        self.view.window().run_command("expand_selection", {"to": "line"})
        start_region = self.view.sel()[0]
        self.view.window().run_command("select_all")
        self.view.sel().subtract(start_region)
        self.view.window().run_command("split_selection_into_lines")
        self.view.window().run_command("move", {"by": "characters", "forward": False})
```

The last line is only to remove selection, leaving multiple cursors at the beginning of selected lines.

Comment: Wow this looks promising - I'm gonna try this as soon as I can!

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm fairly new to the plugins. Should be fun. Begin able to select every other line would be just fantastic. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I also wrote a plugin to do that, but I'm too lazy to publish it, so you can just create a `SelectEveryNthLine.py` file in `Packages/User` and put this code inside:

```py
import sublime
import sublime_plugin

class SelectEveryNthLine( sublime_plugin.TextCommand ):
    def run( self, edit ):

        def on_done( n ):
            n = int( n )

            selections = self.view.sel()

            # if there is nothing selected, then select everything
            if len( selections ) == 1 and selections[0].size() == 0:
                selections.add( sublime.Region( 0, self.view.size() ) )

            new_selections = []

            for sel in selections:
                for i in range( self.view.rowcol( sel.begin() )[0], self.view.rowcol( sel.end() )[0] + 1, n ):
                    line_region = self.view.line( self.view.text_point( i, 0 ) )
                    if not sel.contains( line_region ):
                        continue
                    new_selections.append( line_region )
            selections.clear()
            for sel in new_selections:
                selections.add( sel )

        # firstly ask for the N
        sublime.active_window().show_input_panel( "Enter N to select ever N-th line:", "", on_done, None, None )
```

You can also create file `SelectEveryNthLine.sublime-commands` and put following code inside, to make it accessible from Command Palette:

```py
[
    {
        "caption": "Select every N-th line",
        "command": "select_every_nth_line"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's not a huge amount of lines, you can also of course just hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> (<kbd>Cmd</kbd> on Mac) and click on each line where you want a cursor.

For smaller numbers of lines, this is quicker and easier than running regex commands or adding plugins.